# Consume custom servicestack AuthProvider

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

I'm trying to access my custom AuthProvider (which in inherited from BasicAuthProvider) from ServerEventsClient.
Provider code is very simple ATM

```
public class RoomsAuthProvider : BasicAuthProvider
{
    public RoomsAuthProvider(AppSettings appSettings) : base(appSettings)
    {
    }

    public RoomsAuthProvider()
    {
    }

    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService,
        string userName, string password)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService,
        IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens,
        Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        session.FirstName = "some_firstname_from_db";
        return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
    }
}
```

I'm registering it as usual:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[]
        {
            new RoomsAuthProvider()
        }));

    Plugins.Add(new ServerEventsFeature());
}
```

and my client is:

```
var client = new ServerEventsClient("http://localhost:1337/", "home")
```

trying to authenticate:

```
var authResponse = client.Authenticate(new Authenticate
{
    provider = "RoomsAuthProvider",
    UserName = "test@gmail.com",
    Password = "p@55w0rd",
    RememberMe = true,
});
```

I always get NotFound error and the rror stating that no configuration is set for this AuthProvider. Setting Name and Realm in provider didn't help. Is there another authentication flow for this type of client or I'm missing something? Any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inherit a [BasicAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/BasicAuthProvider.cs) you also inherit it's [provider name](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/BasicAuthProvider.cs#L14) which unless you override it, is by [default is "basic"](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthenticateService.cs#L25) (i.e. it's not the name of inherited class).

But the `BasicAuthProvider` implements [HTTP Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) so you're meant to call it via HTTP Basic Authentication not via a Web Service call.

If you're trying to authenticate via a Web Service call you should inherit from [CredentialsAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/CredentialsAuthProvider.cs) instead which is the authentication method used for authenticating via Username/Password like you're doing in your example. The provider name for `CredentialsAuthProvider` is [credentials](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthenticateService.cs#L26) so your client call would then be:

```
var authResponse = client.Authenticate(new Authenticate
{
    provider = "credentials",
    UserName = "test@gmail.com",
    Password = "p@55w0rd",
    RememberMe = true,
});
```

Comment: I have changed the base class to CredentialsAuthProvider, overriden the name to public new static string Name = "RoomsAuth"; but it didn't work

Comment: @HardLuck that's because the static Name property doesn't do anything on its own, you'd need to change the instance `Provider` property instead - but I'd leave it as-is as it still represents the "credentials" auth provider.